# Linux won't boot after shrinking LVM

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, lvm, fsck

I am using Ubuntu 18.10.

I have a Volume Group and a Logical Volume mounted on /home

Volume Group is /dev/mapper/volume_group and Logical Volume which is mounted on /home is /dev/mappper/volume_group_lv-home

This Logical Volume had 20G.

I used the following commands to decrease size of the LVM volume_group_lv-home, which is mounted in /home:

```
resize2fs /dev/mappper/volume_group_lv-home 5G
lvreduce -L 20G /dev/mappper/volume_group_lv-home
```

After i did those two commands above i did a reboot.

After the reboot i started getting the following messages, and it won't get past this:

```
"/dev/mappper/volume_group_lv-root: recovering journal"
"/dev/mappper/volume_group_lv-root: clean "
```

CTRL + ALT + F2 through F7 doesnt show anything. Only a blank black screen.
Can someone help me?

Comment: There is not enough information here to offer specific help just yet. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) a more complete set of commands you used to shrink the volume (2) the size of the disk (3) the new size of the volume (4) the file system type. With this, it may be possible to correct the LVM headers so that the volume is valid again 

Comment: I added more details of exactly what i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around i came up with the following:

I booted into my server using a Live Debian distro, mounted /root and edited fstab to the way it was previously.

After i rebooted the problem was solved...